# Is There A Way To Embed A Comment Box In An Email Message?

Tags: javascript, email, comments, embed, newsletter

I send out a Movie Review Newsletter and people have asked me if I could make the emails more interactive with a comment thread or comment box.  They would like to be able to start comment threads in the email itself rather than replying to the email and the messiness of having all these multiple conversations going on through one chain of emails.

Any assistance with helping me figure out if it is possible to embed a comment box or comment thread within the body of an e-mail message would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+form+in+emal)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: You could place a link to a web service that you create for storing comments.   Other than that Emails are pretty dumb, so you don't have the power you get with a normal HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Placing any JavaScript code into email bodies is really a bad idea. For example, for security reasons, Microsoft Office Outlook blocks JS code execution and any form elements are not supported in message bodies.

Instead, I'd suggest placing hyperlinks that can lead to a web page where users can leave their feedback. Also you may consider developing a plug-in to a client application which can interact with a user based on the email content.